# How to populate data into ASP.NET MVC 5.2 class using bootstrap "contact us" form to my email?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, form-submit, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a site with a "Contact Us" page and I want my users to be able to use that form to send me an email.  My email, of course, does not show, but I have the user place their first name last name, email address, and a message in a bootstrap 4.xxx (the latest one) form and hit send.  However, when I hit send the data does not get populated to the ActionResult method in my HomeController.

I also noticed an error with my javascript function on-click submit, the error is it is null.  I am in the process of using the Route-Config to help catch the data, but I am not sure which is the right path at this point.  I do not want to use the Html helpers (just the HtmlBeginForm).

I have had many iterations and so this not exactly the best, but it is enough to see my issues.

HomeController:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Email(FormCollection form)`enter code here`
    {
        var firstName = form["firstName"];
        var lastName = form["lastNname"];
        var email = form["senderEmail"];
        var message = form["emailMessage"];
        var x = await ContactForm(firstName, lastName, email, message);
        return RedirectToAction("Send");
    }

    private async Task<ActionResult> ContactForm(string firstName, string lastName, string email, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage messages = new MailMessage();
            messages.To.Add("marketing@gmail.com");
            messages.From = new MailAddress(email);
            messages.Subject = "Contact Page Email";
            messages.Body = message;
            messages.IsBodyHtml = true;

            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var credential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = "marketing@gmail.com",
                    Password = "*****"
                };
                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = "smtp-mail-outlook.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(messages);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        ...
```

HTML:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Email", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <form name="sendMessage" id="contactForm">                           
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName" name="firstName">
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter a first name.</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastName" name="lastName">
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter a last name.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail">Email Address:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="username@emailaddress.com" name="senderEmail">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="emailMessage">Message:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="5" name="emailMessage"></textarea>
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter a message.</div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " onclick="myFunction()">Send</button>
                    </form>
```

Email with first name, last name, sender's email, message in my inbox.

Answer (score 0):

You are using FormCollection in your Email method which requires the cshtml to have a name parameter for the fields which is missing in your code.

Also, you don't really require javascript function to submit the form unless you want to intervene and do some validations. Hence, please try removing that as well.

Please try to change your cshtml to below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Email", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
            <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName" name="firstName">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter a first name.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastName" name="lname">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter a last name.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="username@emailaddress.com" name="senderEmail">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="emailMessage">Message:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="5" name="smessage"></textarea>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Enter a message.</div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send</button>
}
```

Comment: I changed it already before the post.  I have been up all night.  I was too tired to change it for the post.  I will correct that here shortly.  I added the javascript because I thought that would help populate the form, but it didn't.

Comment: please also give the contents of your RouteConfig.cs file so it can be validated as well

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  I need to change this post.  Not good posting when you are exhausted.  I am gonna get some rest and redo the question.

Comment: You have two forms. Try getting rid of this `<form name="sendMessage" id="contactForm"></form> `

Comment: @Tyddlywink, well spotted, I had overlooked it. Edited the answer now. Looking at OPs last comment I guess he was not interested in the solution so I had abandoned it.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal I oopsed.  This comment was meant for his question.  But this will work as well.  If he's interested in a solution yours should do it for him now.  Thanks.